# difference between was boggled and boggled

Tags: grammar

I saw first sentence in dictionary and I wonder if we could consider second one as an alternative:
He boggled at the suggestion.
He was boggled at the suggestion.

Comment: The verb boggle can be used with or without an object. The first sentence doesn't have an object. "He boggled." The second sentence is in the passive voice, which usually  is used when we want to focus attention on the person or thing affected by something. In the sentence "He was boggled…" the subject "he" is the object (him) in the active sentence: Something boggled him.(active) - He was boggled by… (passive).  Therefore I think **by** is the correct preposition to use here.

Answer (score 2):

Both are possible. A person (or their mind) can boggle at something, or be boggled by, or at, something.

[Boggle](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/boggle)